# Difference between oracore and oracore3 folder?

Tags: oracle, installation

I'm trying to fix a timezone file mismatch between a server and a client. The server points to timezone_36 files and the client points to timezone 32. I got a patch from our oracle supplier but it creates a oracore3 folder, that according to the genezi command, the client is not looking at.

Manually moving the dat files work for all files except for timezlrg_36.dat, which after I've moved it the sqlplus command no longer works and I can't connect to Oracle anymore, theres no error it just doesn't work.

So my question is, what is the difference between these folders and how do I change what path the timezone files need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you applied a defective patch.

[Bug 33387456 : PATCH 32327201 - DSTV36 ON MICROSOFT WINDOWS X64 DOES NOT WORK](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=33387456)

```
=====================
DETAILED PROBLEM DESCRIPTION
============================
Patch 32327201 - DSTv36 on Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) does not work
 
DIAGNOSTIC ANALYSIS
===================
The DSTv36 timezone files are installed in %ORACLE_HOME%\oracore3\zoneinfo
folder instead of %ORACLE_HOME%\oracore\zoneinfo.
```

The patch was re-released a few days ago. Download the new one and apply that one.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you. I'll contact our dbas to send us the correct patch. Do you happen to know if you need a different patch for 32 bit oracle clients?

Comment: @Sixsmith That is the same patch (number) released for different platforms, so after all, yes, you need different patch archives for 32-bit and 64-bit software on Windows.